# pandas - how to retrieve idices of minima at a deep level of DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Here is my test DataSet with MultiIndex -

```
In [126]: sumdf
Out[126]:
                     sum
frame face lmark
0     NaN  NaN       0.0
30    0.0  1.0    1113.0
           2.0    1064.0
           3.0    1212.0
45    0.0  1.0    1084.0
           2.0    1133.0
           3.0    1181.0
```

I can the retrieve the indices of the minimum value of the whole DataSet with -

```
In [127]: sumdf.idxmin()
Out[127]:
sum    (0, nan, nan)
dtype: object
```

but how can I determine the indices of the minima at the `lmark` level?

ie. I want to retrieve something like -

```
(45, 0.0, 1.0) - minimum where lmark = 1.0
(30, 0.0, 2.0) - minimum where lmark = 2.0
(30, 0.0, 3.0) - minimum where lmark = 3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, it's `idxmin` with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(level='lmark')['sum'].idxmin()
```

Output:

```
lmark
1.0    (45, 0.0, 1.0)
2.0    (30, 0.0, 2.0)
3.0    (45, 0.0, 3.0)
Name: sum, dtype: object
```